# Function with maximum possible sum of some of its k consecutive numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

As title, can anyone help me write a function return maximum possible sum of some of its k consecutive numbers 
(numbers that follow each other in order.) of a given array of positive integers. Thank you!

[image: example]

[image: exampl]

[image: Answer]

I have read the answer but can anyone show me how its work? i just dont understand those code about?

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: Show us your code first.

Comment: I'm stuck at idea, so can you guys suggest?

Comment: I saw this exact same problem posted as a question yesterday.  The guy at least posted something that couldn't pass the time limit restriction.

Comment: Please post your code with the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and describe what is the problem with your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, you can do this with the help of traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

First of all, you need to find the maximum value of your input array, then you should pop it and according to the iteration count, iterate to find the next maximum value. Then after you find all the maximum values you need to sum them up at last.

```js
function maxOfSumChain(arr, length) {
  const maxArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const max = Math.max(...arr);
    maxArr.push(max);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max), 1);
  }

  return maxArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

console.log(maxOfSumChain([1, 3, 2, 6, 2], 3));
console.log(maxOfSumChain([1, 3, 2], 2));
```